# Python web scraping IndexError using requests and lxml from site "https://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml?curr=01"

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping

I successfully scraped from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) using the following code, but when I try it on "https://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml?curr=01" I get an error:

```
---> 20 print(tree[0].text_content())
```

`IndexError: list index out of range`

my code is:

```
import requests 
from lxml import html 

# url to scrape data from 
link = 'https://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml?curr=01'

# path to particular element 
path = '/CURRENCIES/LAST_UPDATE'

response = requests.get(link) 
byte_string = response.content 

# get filtered source code 
source_code = html.fromstring(byte_string) 

# jump to preferred html element 
tree = source_code.xpath(path) 

# print texts in first element in list 
print(tree[0].text_content())
```

I would like to scrape the LAST_UPDATE and RATE items.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure about what you looking for ! have a look on my answer.

Comment: if index is out of range, then you need to see what tree is.  You my have an incorrect xpath passed into it

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `url` directly as you calling a different url firstly which i don't know why ! all you need is just calling the url directly and then parse it ! you don't need to convert bytes to text as you can use bs4 `.text`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml?/CURRENCIES/LAST_UPDATE')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')

for update in soup.findAll('LAST_UPDATE'):
    print(update.text)
for rate in soup.findAll('RATE'):
    print(rate.text)
```

Output:

```
2019-12-06
3.463
4.5463
3.1887
3.8434
2.3706
2.6287
0.5144
0.3791
0.2368
0.3653
3.5052
4.8841
0.0229
0.2145
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working solution that uses no external libraries (just python core libraries)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import http.client

connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.boi.org.il")
connection.request("GET", "/currency.xml?curr=01")
response = connection.getresponse()


if response.code == 200:
    root = ET.fromstring(response.read())
    print('LAST_UPDATE: {}'.format(root.find('.//LAST_UPDATE').text))
    print('RATE: {}'.format(root.find('.//RATE').text))
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CURRENCIES>
  <LAST_UPDATE>2019-12-06</LAST_UPDATE>
  <CURRENCY>
    <NAME>Dollar</NAME>
    <UNIT>1</UNIT>
    <CURRENCYCODE>USD</CURRENCYCODE>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <RATE>3.463</RATE>
    <CHANGE>-0.115</CHANGE>
  </CURRENCY>
</CURRENCIES>
```

output

```
LAST_UPDATE: 2019-12-06
RATE: 3.463
```